# Get data based on column name

Tags: c#, for-loop

How to use `Datarow` to retrieve data based on column name? I am trying to loop the db data from my first looping

```
//Trying to get data
DataRow dr = dsResult.Tables[1].Rows[0];
//trying to get data successful 

//what i trying to achieve is to retrieve data from database based on rows index and 
     column name
for(int i =0; i <datagridview.Rows.Count ; i++){

   string a = dr['ColumnName'].['RowsIndex'].toString(); //Failed

}
```

Comment: what is the error exeption?

Comment: why not dr['ColumnName'].ToString()?

Comment: Hi cuong Le, because i want to loop the column to a datagridview

Comment: hi spajce, syntax errors, no such function

Comment: @CheemunLow, you want to get the value of every rows in a datagridview . Why don't you use datagridview.Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString() to get the value?

Comment: @Tonix no, that is another error `:D`

Comment: Hi Tonix, the ID doesnt display in datagrid but stored in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dataTable.Rows[i]; //Where the RowIndex
            string a = dr[0].ToString();    //Where the ColumnIndex or ColumnName
        }
```

Comment: hi, it not allow me to put datarow[column name][i], no such thing

Comment: @CheemunLow check my final answer

Comment: spajce, my data doesnt display in datagridview, that y i cannot use the datagridview to retrieve the data that i want =(

Comment: oh i see.. your main problem you cannot display the data to `dataGridView`, have your tried the `dataSource`? `datagridview.DataSource = yourDataTable`?

Comment: spajce i am trying ur answer now=)

Answer (score 1):

Try ?

```
dr.Rows[RowsIndex]['ColumnName'].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the period after the `'columnName'` specification, and putting `rows[i]["columnName"]` rather than `[columnName][rows]`?